# Start and restart python programs in two cmd windows

Tags: python, powershell, cmd

I have two python scripts that constantly pull information from the web. I want to run them in two different cmd windows because I like to see their logging information that gets printed to the window. 
At the moment, I open the cmd window A and type:

```
cd "my_directory"
python myscript1
```

Then, I open a new cmd window B and type

```
cd "my_directory"
python myscript2
```

Because I want to restart the script every hour, I manually kill and restart them... 
I would like to automize this process in a single program.

Comment: ***"Because I want to restart the script every hour"*** - Can you tell us why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you set a time limit for a PowerShell script to run for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019954/how-can-you-set-a-time-limit-for-a-powershell-script-to-run-for)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cmd shell has command `start` that can be used. With `/wait` parameter, one can wait for process' to finish. Create a main script that starts Python programs in separate sessions and wait for the second one to finish before looping the script. Like so,

```
rem main.cmd
:begin
start first.cmd
start /wait second.cmd
goto :begin
```

The first.cmd contains just a call to the Python script:

```
rem first.cmd
python foo.py
exit
```

The second.cmd will call different script:

```
rem second.cmd
python bar.py
exit
```

Comment: That already looks nice - thank you. However, the python scripts do not stop but run in an infinite loop until I cancel them. Therefore, I guess the /wait command is no good? (I am not at home  and will not be for a while and thus cannot check myself whether it works without the /wait) Is the /wait necessary ?