# How to schedule a powershell script to run from 00:00:30 to 11:59:59 and then again run at 00:00:30 on next day

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have written a script to ping a certain IP and store it in file.. I want to run to from 00:00:30 to 11:59:59. The reason why I want to do this is because there is another script which will copy the same file and move it to another folder starting at 00:00:00 everyday.

How Should I achieve this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can create different task scheduler from windows and can use your script inside task to invoke that. Please refer below url for details:https://windowsreport.com/schedule-tasks-windows-10/

Comment: Yes.. But the question is how to stop at 11:59:59 and re run the script again at 00:0030.. I am not able to find any trigger for that..

Comment: For example If I use below setting I will not be able to stop at 11:59:59 and re-run the task on next date 00:00:30 just right after 31 secs.. How to attach a image here by the way,..

Comment: could you please explore timer approach in powershell. Please refer this post. >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019954/how-can-you-set-a-time-limit-for-a-powershell-script-to-run-for